# How to set a "#+SETUPFILE: .xxx.setup" as dir local?

Tags: org-mode, directory-local-variables

I need this line in every my org files. It's tedious to include it in everyone of them.

Comment: You can use one of the many template systems to include it whenever the file is created. See e.g. `autoinsert.el` for a very simple system - I'm sure there are more complicated ones with more capabilities. Do `C-v f auto-insert` and go from there. Also check the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode).

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your relay. But what I want is to get rid of this line in my org files, to make it exist in some dir local variable form. I have no idea what variable name should I use.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without changing Org mode code: AFAIK there is no such variable. You might want to submit an RFE to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm capitalizing on the `org-export-before-parsing-hook`, which runs before the buffer is parsed by the back-end.

dir-local.el

```
((org-mode . ((org-export-before-parsing-hook . ((lambda (bach-end) 
                                                   (goto-char 0)
                                                   (insert "#+SETUPFILE: ./assets/my-theme-readtheorg.setup\n")))))))
```

It won't actually alter your file.

For `org-export-before-parsing-hook` is risky, you may consider to add it to `safe-local-variable-values` to avoid Emacs's querying.